# RSS Parser with CustomAdapter using AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, rss

Hi below is my working code to parse RSS and populate it in ListView, but I want to add CustomAdapter rather than simple Adapter, so that I can add an ImageView in ListView and design my own ListView. Can someone help with code.

SocialFeeds.Java

```
public class SocialFeeds extends Activity {

// A reference to the local object
private SocialFeeds local;

    /** 
     * This method creates main application view
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set view
        setContentView(R.layout.tweet);

        // Set reference to this activity
        local = this;

        GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

        // Start download RSS task
        task.execute("https:url");

        // Debug the thread name
        Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem>> {

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SocialFeeds.this);


        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Debug the task thread name
            Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ITCRssReader", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
                dialog.setMessage("Please Wait.");
                dialog.setCancelable(true); 
                dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

            if (dialog.isShowing()) 
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            // Get a ListView from main view
            ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Create a list adapter
            ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            // Set list adapter for the ListView
            itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Set list view item click listener
            itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));

        }       

    }

}
```

ListListener.java

```
public class ListListener extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

// List item's reference
List<RssItem> listItems;
// Calling activity reference
Activity activity;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;
WebView wv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
    listItems = aListItems;
    activity  = anActivity;
}

/**
 * Start a browser with url from the rss item.
 */
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    /*Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));
    activity.startActivity(i);*/

}

}
```

RssParseHandler.java

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<RssItem> rssItems;

// Used to reference item while parsing
private RssItem currentItem;

// Parsing title indicator
private boolean parsingTitle;
// A buffer used to build current title being parsed
private StringBuffer currentTitleSb;

// Parsing pubDate indicator
private boolean parsingpubDate;
// A buffer used to build current pubDate being parsed
private StringBuffer currentpubDateSb;

// Parsing description indicator
private boolean parsingDescription;
// A buffer used to build current description being parsed
private StringBuffer currentDescriptionSb;

// Parsing link indicator
private boolean parsingLink;

public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem(0, qName, qName, qName);
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;
        currentTitleSb = new StringBuffer();
    } 

    else if ("pubDate".equals(qName)) {
        parsingpubDate = true;
        currentpubDateSb = new StringBuffer();
    } 

    else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingDescription = true;
        currentDescriptionSb = new StringBuffer();
    } 

    else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } 

    else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;
        // Set item's title when we parse item->title tag not the channel title tag
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's title here
            currentItem.setTitle(currentTitleSb.toString());
        }

    } 

    else if ("pubDate".equals(qName)) {
        parsingpubDate = false;
        // Set item's pubDate when we parse item->pubDate tag not the channel pubDate tag
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's pubDate here
            currentItem.setpubDate(currentpubDateSb.toString());
        }

    } 

    else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingDescription = false;
        // Set item's description when we parse item->description tag not the channel description tag
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's description here
            currentItem.setDescription(currentDescriptionSb.toString());
        }

    } 

    else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Here we append the title to the buffer due to network issues.
            // Sometimes this characters method is called multiple times for a tag contents.
            currentTitleSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    } 

    if (parsingpubDate) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Here we append the pubDate to the buffer due to network issues.
            // Sometimes this characters method is called multiple times for a tag contents.
            currentpubDateSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }

    if (parsingDescription) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Here we append the description to the buffer due to network issues.
            // Sometimes this characters method is called multiple times for a tag contents.
            currentDescriptionSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }

    else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

RssReader.java

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<RssItem> rssItems;

// Used to reference item while parsing
private RssItem currentItem;

// Parsing title indicator
private boolean parsingTitle;
// A buffer used to build current title being parsed
private StringBuffer currentTitleSb;

// Parsing pubDate indicator
private boolean parsingpubDate;
// A buffer used to build current pubDate being parsed
private StringBuffer currentpubDateSb;

// Parsing description indicator
private boolean parsingDescription;
// A buffer used to build current description being parsed
private StringBuffer currentDescriptionSb;

// Parsing link indicator
private boolean parsingLink;

public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem(0, qName, qName, qName);
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;
        currentTitleSb = new StringBuffer();
    } 

    else if ("pubDate".equals(qName)) {
        parsingpubDate = true;
        currentpubDateSb = new StringBuffer();
    } 

    else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingDescription = true;
        currentDescriptionSb = new StringBuffer();
    } 

    else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } 

    else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;
        // Set item's title when we parse item->title tag not the channel title tag
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's title here
            currentItem.setTitle(currentTitleSb.toString());
        }

    } 

    else if ("pubDate".equals(qName)) {
        parsingpubDate = false;
        // Set item's pubDate when we parse item->pubDate tag not the channel pubDate tag
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's pubDate here
            currentItem.setpubDate(currentpubDateSb.toString());
        }

    } 

    else if ("description".equals(qName)) {
        parsingDescription = false;
        // Set item's description when we parse item->description tag not the channel description tag
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Set item's description here
            currentItem.setDescription(currentDescriptionSb.toString());
        }

    } 

    else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Here we append the title to the buffer due to network issues.
            // Sometimes this characters method is called multiple times for a tag contents.
            currentTitleSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    } 

    if (parsingpubDate) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Here we append the pubDate to the buffer due to network issues.
            // Sometimes this characters method is called multiple times for a tag contents.
            currentpubDateSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }

    if (parsingDescription) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            // Here we append the description to the buffer due to network issues.
            // Sometimes this characters method is called multiple times for a tag contents.
            currentDescriptionSb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }

    else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

RssItem.java

```
public class RssItem {


public int imageId;
// item title
public String title;
// item link
public String link;
// item pubDate
public String pubDate;
// item description
public String description;



public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

public String getpubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setpubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public RssItem(int imageId, String title, String description, String link) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" + description + "\n" + pubDate;
}

}
```

Comment: Looking forward if someone has hands on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below url

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-rss-feed-reader-example.html

RSS Parser with CustomAdapter using AsyncTask

Comment: Thanks a ton Hari, That was a great help from you.

Comment: Yes Hari, I runned, It is working very well. This code of yours is really helpful, as after Android 4.0 all the internet task are to be run in Async Task, so if you find older tutorials for RSS all would be done in main thread out of which none would work. So good job...Keep sharing...